# Determine how similar two arrays are in PostgreSQL

Tags: arrays, postgresql

I'm aware you can compare two arrays in PostgreSQL to see if the elements in one are contained in the elements of another like so,

```
SELECT ARRAY[1,2] <@ ARRAY[1,2,3] --> true
```

Is there any way to get # of matches or say "if matches 2 of 3" ??

```
SELECT ARRAY[1,2] ?? ARRAY[1,2,3] --> 2/3 or 66.6666%
```

I'm open to interesting solutions.. I want to take an array and ultimately say it must match 2 of 3 elements from another array in an inline query.. or >= 66% or something of that nature.

Ideally like this..

```
SELECT * FROM SOMETABLE WHERE ARRAY[1,2] ?? ARRAY[1,2,3] >= 66.66666666666667
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

From here [Array functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html)

```
with match as 
    (select count(a) as match_ct from unnest(ARRAY[1,2] ) as a 
join 
    (select * from  unnest(ARRAY[2,1,3]) as b)  t on a=t.b) 
select 
     match_ct/total_ct::numeric from match,  
     (select count(*) as total_ct from unnest(ARRAY[1,2], ARRAY[2,1,3]) as t(a, b)) as total ;
        ?column?        
------------------------
 0.66666666666666666667
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a function for that:

```
CREATE FUNCTION array_similarity(anyarray, anyarray)
   RETURNS double precision
   LANGUAGE sql
   IMMUTABLE STRICT AS
$$SELECT 100.0 * count(*) / cardinality($2)
FROM unnest($1) AS a1(e1)
WHERE ARRAY[e1] <@ $2$$;
```